# `android create` gradle project with gradle 2.7

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I am trying to make a gradle-build android project without android studio using the `android` tool.  I have gotten this far but I cannot figure out what version number to give android. So I can successfully build the project

```
android create project -t 1 -n cliPrj -a Main -k cheezsteak.cliPrj -p cliPrj -g -v ???
```

It's not the gradle version.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the **Gradle Android plugin version**. In my case, it's 1.2.3, which I found in my build.gradle file for my project in Android Studio as com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3

More info about the gradle plugin here: https://developer.android.com/tools/revisions/gradle-plugin.html